# Can someone help with renaming a tag?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I am main committer and release manager of the android-maven-plugin and recently found out about the [maven-android-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-android-plugin) tag on Stack Overflow. I would like to suggest a rename of the tag or at least the creation of a synonym. Since I have just found out about the tag (I used to just look for android and maven tags separately now and then) I do not have the right to do that yet.

Imho the correct name for the tag would be [android-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/android-maven-plugin) since this is the official project name. It used to be maven-android-plugin but for well over a year we have changed to the new name as required due to restrictions of not being a ASF project..

Could someone more privileged than me please do that?

Comment: I support this motion. Better keep all ducks in a row. And OP could even point at the tag here from the offcial site for the project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do that on your own since you have 8k+ rep ?

I did it. You should now [propose a tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/89171) for [android-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/android-maven-plugin).

Old excerpt:

> The android maven plugin allows building of Android applications and libraries with Apache Maven and provides many more features

Old full tag wiki:

> android-maven-plugin (formerly maven-android-plugin) brings the power of Maven to Android project development. It lets you build Android application (apk) projects as well as application libraries (apklib) with Maven, with simple and powerful configuration. It has features like deploying to all attached devices, running instrumentation tests, taking screenshots, running lint, zipalign, proguard and many more.
>
> Home Page: http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/

Comment: I have done that now (and btw the original text was from me as well..). Now I would just love a retag of the existing questions and a synonym set up... which I can't do.

Comment: @ManfredMoser I know :)